# Combining deferred responses

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

Is it possible, when using jQuery Deferred's `$.when` to combine the responses into an array?

```
var promise = $.when(
    ajaxRequest1,
    ajaxRequest2
);

promise.done(callback);
```

The "callback" function looks like `function callback(resp, options)`. Note how it only accepts a single response.

I thought the following might work, but did not.

```
var promise = $.when(
    ajaxRequest1,
    ajaxRequest2
);
promise.then(function(resp1, resp2) {
    return [resp1, resp2];
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that jQuery resolves its ajax promises with 3 arguments, which then become an array of values when you are using `$.when` on multiple promises. To get only the `data` (the first argument of each ajax callback), use

```
var promise = $.when(
    ajaxRequest1,
    ajaxRequest2
).then(function(resp1, resp2) {
    return [resp1[0], resp2[0]];
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Turns out the ".then" needs to be chained to ".when" (like your code sample shows). If you do "promise.then()", it will not work as expected, which makes sense because you're operating on the promise subset, not the full deferred object.

Comment: Well, you just have to use the return value of the `.then()` call instead of throwing it away. Whether it operates on a variable or is directly chained, and whether you call it on a deferred or on a promise doesn't really matter.

Comment: Check out this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jbarreiros/0jyhrsmr/. It gives different results depending on whether it is chained or not.

Comment: @jbarreiros: Sorry for being unclear. I meant [this](http://jsfiddle.net/0jyhrsmr/3/) by "not chained directly to `when`". Of course you need to use the result of the the `then()` call.